# inputs from a drop down list returns a table from another sheet in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table in a sheet that contains the following information

A2=H,A3=C, A4=L,

For Climate zone-1
B2=1,B3=2,,B4=3

For Climate zone-2
C2=3,C3=2,C4=1

Now in another sheet I have  a  drop down list of climate zone-1 and climate zone-2.
I want to show the climate zone -1 data (both cell A  and cell B data)if I select climate zone -1 from drop down list. same for the other.

Is it possible to do without using VBA or pivot table?

Thanks.

Comment: do you need a join between sheet1 and sheet2?

Comment: so the question is "IS IT POSSIBLE WITHOUT VBA OR PIVOT"...answer is Yes!

Comment: So regardless of where you have picked climate zone 1 or 2, you are looking to display a 2 column by 3 row grid of information on the "OTHER" sheet?

Comment: Yes, I want to join between sheet 1 and sheet 2.

I have put here a simple one. but actually I need to do for 5 column by 6 row grid.I think if I can do for this, whatever the grid size is it can be done. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You need unique headers at the top of the columns in the grid. Then you can use an Index/Match combo to look up the values. Consider this screenshot:

The formula on Sheet2, cell A2 is

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$E$4,ROW(A1),MATCH($A$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$E$1,0))
```

copied down to A4

[image]

Comment: Then, please mark the answer, as explained in the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A1 is your drop down list result and A2:B4 is where you want your data to show and that your source data is on a worksheet called SOURCE.

in A2 enter:

```
=SOURCE!A2
```

copy that down to A3 and A4.  This information never changes as it is the same for Climate 1 and Climate 2

in B3 enter:

```
=IF($A$1="zone-1",SOURCE!B2,SOURCE!C2)
```

copy that down to B3 and B4.

Comment: Since you are using more than two zones of data, take a look at what @Teylyn posted.  Basically use her method but put the formula in B2 and copy down and put `=Sheet1!A2` in A2 and copy down.